# change proxy configuration targets dynamically in angular

Tags: angular

In my angular application, I am using proxy configuration file consisting of some proxies. My file looks like this.

**proxy.conf.json**

```
{
  "/login": {
    "target": "http://w3:8080",
    "changeOrigin":true,
    "secure": false
  },   
  "/api/usersvcs/*": {
    "target": "http://w3:8080",
    "pathRewrite": {"^/api/usersvcs": ""},
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel":"debug"
  },
  "/api/ordersvcs/*": {
    "target": "http://w3:8989",
    "pathRewrite": {"^/api/ordersvcs": ""},
    "changeOrigin":true,
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel":"debug"
  },
  "/api/paymentsvcs/*": {
    "target": "http://w3:9898",
    "pathRewrite": {"^/api/paymentsvcs": ""},
    "changeOrigin":true,
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel":"debug"
  },
}
```

This file is in root directory of my project (outside **src** folder).
Every time I need to change target parameter if I want to work with some other back end services hosted on different ports. In the above file, I am working with **w3** , and then the port numbers after colon.
If I want to work with **w5**, I have to change the entire path targets like this.

```
{
  "/login": {
    "target": "http://w5:8080",
    "changeOrigin":true,
    "secure": false
  },   
  "/api/usersvcs/*": {
    "target": "http://w5:8080",
    "pathRewrite": {"^/api/usersvcs": ""},
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel":"debug"
  },
  "/api/ordersvcs/*": {
    "target": "http://w5:8989",
    "pathRewrite": {"^/api/ordersvcs": ""},
    "changeOrigin":true,
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel":"debug"
  },
  "/api/paymentsvcs/*": {
    "target": "http://w5:9898",
    "pathRewrite": {"^/api/paymentsvcs": ""},
    "changeOrigin":true,
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel":"debug"
  },
}
```

I am using `npm start` command in which I have included `proxy.conf.json` file which looks like below in `package.json`

```
"scripts":{
   ...
   "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json --o",
   ...
},
```

Is it possible to change the target hostnames something like if I use

`npm start w5`

then the proxy file should be like one above with the targets having w5.

Comment: I don't think so, but you can at least use a .js file instead of a .json file (see https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-proxy#multiple-entries), and thus use a variable (or even an environment variable) to avoid repeating yourself.

Comment: got you, but can you please tell me how to pass value to the `proxy.conf.js` file from the command I use to start the project.

Comment: I don't think that's possible.

Answer (score 2):

We achieved this functionality through Environment variables like this:

proxy.conf.js:

```
var process = require("process");
var api_target = process.env.API_TARGET;
console.log('Proxy configuration: ' + api_target);
const PROXY_CONFIG = {
  "/api/*": {
    target: `http://${api_target}`,
    secure: false,
    changeOrigin: true,
    pathRewrite: {"^/api" : ""}
  }
}
module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

package.json:

```
 "start-dev01": "cross-env API_TARGET=sfslmkwpsdev01/api npm start",
```